# Change zIndex using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

It works on the premade divs but on the newly made one, it doesn't work. How do I fix that?

Here's the code on the event for changing the zIndex:

```
$(".widget").mousedown(function (event) {
    var ws = document.getElementById("widget-workspace");
    var list = ws.children, x=0;

    for(x=0;x<ws.children.length;x++){
        console.log(ws.children[x].id);
        $("#"+ws.children[x].id).css("zIndex", 99);
    }

    $(this).css("zIndex", 100);
});
```

Now, here's the code for adding the div:

```
document.getElementById("widget-dialog-button").onclick = function () {
    var ws = document.getElementById("widget-workspace");
    var list = ws.children;
    var x, w = document.getElementById("select-widget");
    var widget = w.options[w.selectedIndex].value;
    var c = document.getElementById("select-widget-color");
    var color = c.options[c.selectedIndex].value;
    var left = 0, top = 25, docWidth = ws.offsetWidth, check;

    for(x=0; x < list.length; x++){
        docWidth -= 325;
        left += 325;
        if(docWidth < 325){
            check = false;
            docWidth = ws.offsetWidth;
            left = 0;
            top += 210;
        }else{
            check = true;
        }
    }

    x-=2;

    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'widget_'+x;
    iDiv.className = 'widget';
    iDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
    iDiv.style.left = left;
    iDiv.style.top = top;
    ws.appendChild(iDiv);

    $(function() {
        $( ".widget" ).draggable();
    });
};
```

If you guys need anything else, feel free to ask.

Comment: What works and what doesn't? What's the problem with your code? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use Jquery 'On' function ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple :

"It works on the premade divs but on the newly made one, it doesn't work. How do I fix that?"

It's normal :

```
$(".widget").mousedown(...);

// should be read as (except that a new var is not created)
var $currentlyExistingWidgets = $(".widget");
$currentlyExistingWidgets.mousedown(...);
```

To each element of class widget currently existing, you bind an event.

If you want to bind events to elements not existing... You have to reconider your way of thinking and then bind an event listener to a container always existing, with an event delegation mechanism and proper filtering.

For example the following code should catch the event for all .widget, created before or after :

```
// http://api.jquery.com/on/
$('body').on('mousedown', '.widget', function() { ... });
```

If you want to search and learn, the key concepts are event bubbling and event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're attaching the `mousedown` listener means that only the element that exist at that point will be listened to. Use the `on` method:

```
// May want to use something other than body
$('body').on('mousedown', '.widget', function() {
    console.log('go');
});
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)